# Facebook Graph API Upload Photo

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

How to upload a picture to the Facebook wall through the Graph API in the Apple documentation? It is provided in Obj C, but I want it in Swift.

Comment: Do you want to share photo on Facebook?

Comment: Just Upload the photo.Just like adding a photo to the album

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26951324/how-do-i-post-a-story-to-facebook-in-swift

Comment: Can i get an example using graph request ? sample code ?